Python arcade - vsync and update_rate
I am going through some arcade library samples and wondering how update_rate of a Window works with vsync -- for example, in my mind, these two should be equivalent (on my macbook pro, with ProMotion enabled, I should be getting a 120Hz refresh rate)
 self.set_vsync(True)

VS:
FPS = 120 # or whatever it needs to be based on hardware
self.set_vsync(False)
self.set_update_rate(1/FPS) 


The vsync=True example seems to yield smoother animation and I am not sure why.
